# Error when rasterizing

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I am trying to create a .asc raster file from shapefiles (which are all in the British National Grid coordinate system) but I keep getting the following error:

GDAL execution console output

Output driver `AAIGrid' not recognised or does not support direct output file creation.

```
         The following format drivers are configured and support direct output:

 -> `VRT'
         
          -> `GTiff'
         
          -> `NITF'
         
          -> `HFA'
         
          -> `ELAS'
         
          -> `MEM'
         
          -> `BMP'
         
          -> `PCIDSK'
         
          -> `PCRaster'
         
          -> `ILWIS'
         
          -> `SGI'
         
          -> `Leveller'
         
          -> `Terragen'
         
          -> `netCDF'
         
          -> `ISIS3'
         
          -> `ISIS2'
         
          -> `PDS4'
         
          -> `VICAR'
         
          -> `ERS'
         
          -> `RMF'
         
          -> `RST'
         
          -> `INGR'
         
          -> `GSBG'
         
          -> `GS7BG'
         
          -> `PDF'
         
          -> `MBTiles'
         
          -> `MRF'
         
          -> `PNM'
         
          -> `PAux'
         
          -> `MFF'
         
          -> `MFF2'
         
          -> `BT'
         
          -> `LAN'
         
          -> `IDA'
         
          -> `GTX'
         
          -> `NTv2'
         
          -> `CTable2'
         
          -> `KRO'
         
          -> `ROI_PAC'
         
          -> `RRASTER'
         
          -> `BYN'
         
          -> `BAG'
         
          -> `NWT_GRD'
         
          -> `ADRG'
         
          -> `SAGA'
         
          -> `GPKG'
         
          -> `NGW'
         
          -> `ENVI'
         
          -> `EHdr'
         
          -> `ISCE'
```

I've tried multiple things to correct this including changing to the WGS84 coordinate system but the error still crops up.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchaneg, what command are you running? Post the whole command.

Comment: As per [help/behavior] please do not include signature, thanks/appreciation or any other chit chat in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message `Output driver AAIGrid not recognised or does not support direct output file creation.`

The AAIGrid driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/aaigrid.html supports only "CreateCopy()", that is, create dataset by copying another.

Use for example GeoTIFF as a direct output format when you rasterize and convert the result into AAIGrid afterwards with gdal_translate.